# Writing jasmine test for looping javascript function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

The function would be,

```
function checkCond(a, b){
    if(a===true){
        if(b===true){
            document.getElementById("theId").innerHtml = "success";
        }
        else if(b===false){
            document.getElementById("theId").innerHtml = "Fails";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("theId").innerHtml = "Required";
        }
    }
    else{
        if(b===true){
            document.getElementById("theId").innerHtml = "success";
        }
    }
}
```

How can we write for jasmine test for the above looping function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any looping in this function, but testing it should be straightforward enough.  For example,

```
beforeEach(function() {
  // setup your dom element.  this depends on your environment and 
  // jasmine version.  see docs.  
});

it('should succeed when both conditions are true', function() {
   checkCond( true, true );
   expect(document.getElementById("theId").innerHtml).toBe "success"
});
```

and so forth.